# How can I enable bonded network interfaces in Ubuntu 13.04/13.10/14.04 using NetworkManager

Tags: networking, network-manager

This question is about network interface bonding in Ubuntu 12.04 Precise and newer (12.10 Quantal/13.04 Raring/13.10 Saucy/14.04 Trusty). Bonding is also known as network interface teaming, [link aggregation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_aggregation), and port trunking.

There are instructions out there for setting up bonding by modifying `/etc/network/interfaces` ([help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBonding), [serverlab.ca](http://www.serverlab.ca/linux/administration/network-bonding-with-ubuntu-13/)) however I can't find any instructions or a tutorial on how to set it up using [NetworkManager](https://projects.gnome.org/NetworkManager/) in Ubuntu.

[image: NetworkManager bond menu]

How do I bond my wired (eth0) and wireless (wlan0) network interfaces together using NetworkManager?

## Additional Info

As of [NetworkManager 0.9.4](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/tree/NEWS?id=0.9.4.0#n12) bonding is supported and NetworkManager 0.9.4 is included in [Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Precise](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/net/network-manager). NetworkManager is then updated in [Ubuntu 12.10 Quantal](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/net/network-manager) to [0.9.6](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/tree/NEWS?id=0.9.6.0#n23) and "slaves" were added in [Ubuntu 13.04 Raring](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/net/network-manager) with [NetworkManager 0.9.8](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/tree/NEWS?id=0.9.8.0#n26)

Answer (score 0):

My answer is not the correct way, and doesn't provide the combined bandwidth of proper bonding, but does provide a sort of quick'n'dirty automatic "failover" that I've found acceptable for a laptop that is sometimes hooked up to ethernet.

Set a static IP address on both the Home Ethernet and Home Wireless profiles that you use, and use identical settings on both connections, including the IP address.  When using wireless and hooking up to ethernet, once the connection is established all packets will begin routing through the ethernet adapter exclusively.  When unplugged, the packets will resume transfer through the wireless, assuming it is still actively connected.

Completely the wrong way to do it, and doesn't provide any of the advanced benefits of bonding, but it will work for most laptop users.

Answer (score -2):

I am using the Newest xUbuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahrir [or however you spell it] or this will work in ANY Ubuntu version or Flavor with or without network manager [UGH, that Network Manager software is a real pain compared to the interfaces definitions file IMHO].

Wouldn't you just sudo apt-get purge network manager and go ahead and use /etc/network/interfaces anyways?  It is there and once you manually specify [or not if you issue ifup [may need to use ifup -a (means all adapters) or possibly ifup after purging net manager it should reach out to DHCP and grab an address].

I use OpenVPN and have to as part of that use /etc/network/interfaces to manually specify my bridge connection and it's options.  Once you define [the default file should just go for DHCP without modification] your connections using the interfaces file you can just issue ifdown -a or ifup -a to disconnect and then reconnect to network after any modifications without restarting the machine.

Last once you use the interfaces file network manager will appear greyed out in the notification area.  This is normal you are no longer using Network Manager you are using ifup and ifdown.

And yes this is related to ifconfig so if you use ifconfig in terminal then you are already used to this system and have used it to view adapter info already ifconfig is part of the same package as ifdown and ifup and should be fully present and ready to go even from a fresh install you don't need to apt-get install anything for this to be usable.

Viola follow any /etc/network/interfaces directions needed and they work [and you get rid of a small annoying piece of software [If you google net manager you see people getting disconnected/reconnected randomly and other misc issues]. If you know how to handle the interfaces file this is FAR more easy AND WAY MORE STABLE [and not hard to learn, only took me roughly 30 min to iron out advanced options like setting the default DNS search domains, enabling promiscuous mode, etc] :-D

Hope that helps.

Comment: LoL, I gave an answer that specifically works and get a negative on it LoL.  Interesting how doing the google search Ubuntu bond network network manager brought up 2 how tos and you can do it both ways [reminder network manager can cause more problems than it ever solves I could have used it to do my bridge but when I did and many have noticed the link is not always stable.  Once you drop Network Manager everything works fine] interfaces way: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBonding net manage way: http://www.lemmster.de/network-bonding-wlan-eth-on-linux-ubuntu.html